# Unable to download 'blotter' package

Tags: r, macos, quantstrat, blotter

I'm currently running on MacOS Sierra, 10.12.6 and I'm running Rstudio Version 1.2.5033.

I'm working on a project that requires the use of the 'quantstrat' package.

I've been trying to install 'quantstrat' package using

"devtools::install_github("braverock/quantstrat")"

and I'm constantly getting this error.

"Downloading GitHub repo braverock/quantstrat@master
Skipping 1 packages not available: blotter
Installing 4 packages: blotter, FinancialInstrument, foreach, iterators
Installing packages into ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error: Failed to install 'quantstrat' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) package ‘blotter’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)"

I've tried upgrading my version of Rstudio and find alternative sources to download 'blotter' but I'm still unable to do so.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: It's not always easy for package developers to use remotes as dependencies (e.g. github). You could try to first install blotter from github: `install_github("braverock/blotter")`

Comment: wow, that did the trick! thank you :)

Comment: while it is in their instructions explicitely on their github page for the installation of quantstrat (https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat#installation), it would help users if in the DESCRIPTION they included a line `Remotes: github::braverock/blotter`. I have a bit too much on my hands to create a Pull request/issue, but maybe you (@AdenNeo) could consider it?